# codiagonal functor and faithfullness

Tags: category-theory

It seems trivial but I am not sure how the codiagonal functor is not faithfull, an example being taken in Awodey's book.

---

The diagonal functor $\Delta$ takes the element $c \in C_0$ of a category to the element $ (c , c) \in (C\times C)_0 $ and an arrow $f : c \rightarrow c' \in C_1 $ to the product arrow $ \langle   f\pi_1, f\pi_2 \rangle \in (C\times C)_1$.

The product category $C\times C$ always exist in $Cat$ and The definition of $\Delta$ correspond to the unique arrow (a functor, in $Cat$) to the product category $C\times C$, when picking the 2 identity functors getting into $C$

The sum category $C+ C$ also exist in $Cat$ and every pair of functor coming from category C into a common object defines a universal arrow out of $C + C$ and into that object. We can as previously pick the identity to define an arrow (functor in Cat) between $C+C$ and $C$  unique wrt to the property that the triangles commutes.

(edit : to clarify in this notation x=a+b means x is **either** $a$ **or** $b$. it's not a good one though. there are constructors, left and right, and the sum type thats it)

The commutation property leads to a description that it takes elements $a+b \in C+C$ coming from `left a` to $a$ and from `right b` to $b$ and similarly for morphism. we can see that it fits the bill for commutation, so it's $\nabla$ the codiagonal functor.

Now, if I choose specific elements $x=a+b$ and $y=c+d$ from $C+C$, I have a $Set$ value function $\nabla_{x,y} : Hom_{C+C}(x,y) \rightarrow Hom_C(\nabla x, \nabla y)$

What he claims is that this is an injective function.

---

We could have the following reasoning about it and say ok, a function from $x=a+b$ to some object $y=c+d$, is either a function from $a$ to $c+d$ or a  function from $b$ to $c+d$.

Now given two functions $f$ and $g$ from $x=a+b$ they could be coming from either $a$ or $b$ and $\nabla$ will unwrap whichever it is.
Now if the unwrapped function are equal, nothing guarantees that they are coming from the same case, $\nabla$ `left h`= $\nabla$`right h` but the arguments are not equal.

---

But owing to the fact that we fixed $x$ earlier we have in fact either

- a pair $f$,$g$ coming from the left case $a$ or
- a pair $f$,$g$ coming from the right case $b$

So if we have equality of $\nabla f= \nabla g$ we do have equality on of the original function $f$ and $g$.

---

On the other hand, $\nabla$ is not injective on arrows using the case mentioned before, where the same function is injected left or right.

---

ps : dont know if my notations are standard.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the category $C + C$ should be. Could you point out the exact reference in Awodey's book? (I assume you are talking of Awodey's *Category Theory* book).

Comment: It is at the beginning of chapter 7 définition 7.1 about faithfullness

Comment: Agree about the sum category. I think it's the category whose objects are either left of some object of C or right of some object of C. Arrows are either from a left or from a right, into a object of C+C

Comment: Ok, so you meant the coproduct.

Comment: yes, we call them sum types in programming. I guess the terminology differs a bit.  Awodey writes it C + C though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that you misunderstood the construction of $C + C$, which denote the coproduct of the category $C$ with itself.

Such category has

- pairs of the form $(0,c)$ or $(1,c)$ as objects, where $c \in C$
- pairs of the form $(0,f)$ or $(1,f)$ as morphisms, where $f$ is a morphism in $C$.

The various category operations are defined in the obvious way:
for instance $\text{source}(0,f)=(0,\text{source}(f))$ and $\text{source}(1,f)=(1,\text{source}(f))$.

Now back to your problem, the codiagonal functor $\nabla \colon C + C \to C$ is the only functor that when composed with the two embeddings
$$i_0 \colon C \to C+C\;\; i_1 \colon C \to C+C$$ 
gives the identity functor: that is $\nabla \circ i_1=\nabla\circ i_2=1_C$.

This implies that this functor is defined by the following equations
$$\nabla(0,\alpha)=\nabla(i_0(\alpha))=\alpha$$
$$\nabla(1,\alpha)=\nabla(i_1(\alpha))=\alpha$$
where $\alpha$ can represent either an object or a morphism of $C$.

This functor is indeed faithful, it is injective when restricted on the $\hom$-sets, but it is not injective as functor, because for every morphism $f$ in $C$ you have that $\nabla(0,f)=\nabla(1,f)$ but $(0,f)\ne(1,f)$.

**Edit:** as an alternative notation, which I think it could be more familiar to programmer and/or computer scientist, one could use $\text{left } c$ for the object $(0,c)$ in $C+C$, $\text{right } c$ for the object $(1,c)$ and similarily for the morphisms.

Comment: well `left a` or `(0,a)`  .. ;)

Comment: left and right are actually some standard injection to sum types in Haskell or Agda, but point well taken about the notation.

Comment: @nicolas yes I know that left and right are the ordinary constructors for the sum type, but since on your profile you didn't give any hint on how much type theory do you know I've opted for some standard notation for coproducts (in $\mathbf {Set}$).

Comment: By the way if you prefer I could edit the answer above and use the left and right constructors :)

Comment: @GiorgioMossa very good explanation and notation. I suggest you do not erase or modify what you have written. Perhaps you might *add* some type theory notation for those more familiar with it.

Comment: I dont understand how your construction of C+C is different from the one I present, as a universal arrow constructed from a pair of arrow coming from C..

Comment: @nicolas maybe he is me that didn't understood your construction, but you said that objects of $C+C$ should be things like $a+b$ where both $a$ and $b$ are objects of $C$, now in my construction such thing don't exists: elements are either elements of the form $(0,x)$ [or if you like $\text{left} x$] or $(1,x)$ [a.k.a. $\text{right} x$].

Comment: I see. this "notation" a+b $\in C+C$ is bad enough for it to be called wrong